# Limit MailKit SmtpClient to specific IP address or NIC

Tags: c#, ip-address, smtpclient, mailkit

If `MailKit` `SmtpClient` is used on a system with more than one public `IP address`, is there a way of telling it what `IP address` to use or limit it to using a certain `NIC`?

Comment: Usually you try all IP until you make a connection.  The way if a connection already exists and fails you try the next until you find a valid connection.

Comment: Set `SmtpClient.LocalEndPoint` property to the desired local ip address.

Comment: @Evk: Sooo obvious. Wonder why I didn't see it. Thank you for pointing it out for me.

Comment: @Evk, please add as an answer